# JPA : Why does Lazy Loading happen in this case?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

- springBootVersion = 2.2.2.RELEASE

The Jpa Lazy Loading options does not work.

##### Executed

`VoteBox Entity - findById(...) or findAllBy()...`

anyway,, find VoteBox

##### Result

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        ...
    from
        VoteDB.dbo.VoteBox votebox0_ 
    where
        votebox0_.ID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.haru.poll_book.entity.PollsVote */ select
        ...
    from
        VoteDB.dbo.PollsVote pollsvote0_ 
    where
        pollsvote0_.PollsID=? 
        and pollsvote0_.VoteID=?
```

If you look up PollsVote, you don't look up VoteBox, but if you look up VoteBox.
However, if you are looking up VoteBox, you are looking up PollsVote unconditionally.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me the cause.

#### PollsVote

```java
@Entity
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(
                        name = "UK_PollsVote_PollsID_VoteID",
                        columnNames = {"PollsID", "VoteID"}
                )
        }
)
public class PollsVote implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PollsID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Polls polls;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VoteID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Vote vote;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pollsVote", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<VoteBox> voteBoxList;

    ...
}
```

#### VoteBox

```java
@Entity
public class VoteBox implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "PollsID", referencedColumnName = "PollsID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "VoteID", referencedColumnName = "VoteID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false),
    })
    private PollsVote pollsVote;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PollsID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Polls polls;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VoteID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Vote vote;

    ...
}
```

##### Executed

`VoteBox Entity - findById(...) or findAllBy()...`

anyway,, find VoteBox

##### Result

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        ...
    from
        VoteDB.dbo.VoteBox votebox0_ 
    where
        votebox0_.ID=?

(End)
```

I want Lazy Loading!